# Generic Lambda Expression Call with Or expression

Tags: .net, generics, lambda

I have an extension method that filters out a list and returns only the persons who lives in Montreal and New York, for example.

```
var persons = List<Person>();
var acceptedCities = new List{"Montreal", "New York"};

myList.Where(p => p.City, acceptedCities );
```

The extension method looks like this

```
 public static IQueryable<Tsource> Where<Tsource, Tproperty>(this IQueryable<Tsource> source, Expression<Func<Tsource, Tproperty>> property, IList<int?> accpetedValues)
        {
            var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name;

            if (propertyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            if (accpetedValues == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                return source;

            var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tsource), "item");
            var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(item, propertyName);

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tsource, bool>>(Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { typeof(Tproperty) },
                                             Expression.Constant(accpetedValues), selector), item);
            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
```

Let say that some person does not have any city specified, I need to get them also, then I wanted to modify my method to add an OR exrpession, but I can't make it work.

```
  var contains = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { typeof(Tproperty) },
                                             Expression.Constant(accpetedValues), selector);
            var isNull = Expression.Call(typeof(int?), "Equals", new[] { typeof(Tproperty) }, Expression.Constant(null), selector);
            var orExpression = Expression.Or(contains, isNull);

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tsource, bool>>(orExpression, item);
```

Comment: It might be easier to answer this if you could explain _why_ all the Where function is needed?  Doesn't it all just achieve the same as writing `myList.Where(p => acceptedCities.Contains(p.City));` and then to also include the persons with a missing city would just be `myList.Where(p => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p.City) || acceptedCities.Contains(p.City));` (using the normal LINQ Where function)

Comment: The reason is it's an extension method on a IQueryable<T> type, so I can't just write a query as you say because there is no way to know the name of the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it as this

```
 public static IQueryable<Tsource> Where<Tsource, Tproperty>(this IQueryable<Tsource> source, Expression<Func<Tsource, Tproperty>> property, IList<int?> accpetedValues)
        {
            var propertyName = ((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name;

            if (propertyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentException();

            if (accpetedValues == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                return source;

            var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Tsource), "item");
            var selector = Expression.PropertyOrField(item, propertyName);

            var containsExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Contains", new[] { typeof(Tproperty) },
                                                     Expression.Constant(accpetedValues), selector);

            var isNullExpression = Expression.Equal(selector, Expression.Constant(null));
            var orExpression = Expression.OrElse(isNullExpression, containsExpression);

            var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Tsource, bool>>(orExpression, item);
            return source.Where(predicate);
        }
```